# Unexpected package version with npx command

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

Versioned package doesn't run with `npx` (`npm exec`) when the package has already been installed globally with npm. The environment is Windows 10, Node 16, NPM 8.

`npx npm@6 -v` results in output:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  npm@6
Ok to proceed? (y) y
8.5.2
```

Subsequent `npx npm@6 -v` call skips the installation to cache and runs globally installed package. Same for other global packages. I can verify that correct package versions are installed to `npm-cache/_npx` but not sure what happens with them next

I believe this has been changed since NPM 6, `npx` cache is used

I wonder what happens inside. Is it a known issue? Any workarounds to run versioned global packages while keeping the default one installed?

Answer (score 1):

i have not been able to reproduce this under linux.
(using npm/npx v. 8.5.5)

```
> npx npm@6 -v 
Need to install the following packages:
  npm@6
Ok to proceed? (y) y
6.14.16
```

maybe the issue fixes itself if you update, but i could also be a bug in the windows implementation of npm.

for the time being you could also try to run your program under WSL (windows subsystem for linux).

i am sorry for this somewhat unpleasing answer, but i also couldn't find any better reason for this issue

Comment: It's actually a worthy post, I checked, and it can't be reproduced on Linux indeed, at least with nvm. Did you use it either?

Comment: i actually just used out-of-the-box npm (installed on arch linux using pacman)

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Still hope there's a quick fix on windows but that's a point to start from any way.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, you can run the command under WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). The reason for this is because there might be a bug in Windows.

---

To install WSL, you can follow the following steps.

1. Make sure you are running *Windows 10 version 2004 and higher (Build 19041 and higher)* or *Windows 11*. To check this, you can open *Run* (using <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), and typing `winver`. You can check the version here.

   See the GIF below for a visual representation of how to do it.

   [image: Run GIF]

   <sup>This GIF was made in a Windows 7 virtual machine.</sup>
2. Run the following command in PowerShell or Command Prompt (**running as administrator**).

   ```
   $ wsl --install
   ```

   This should restart your machine, and add the Ubuntu distribution to WSL 2.

For more information on the installation steps, see [Microsoft's official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

---

Running the commands in WSL should help resolve the issue.

```
$ npx npm@6 -v
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will require to move the whole project under WSL

Comment: Are there any issues in that? You can use the built-in Visual Studio Code WSL terminal too.

Comment: Yes, there are. The project may not require the overhead of WSL otherwise - both in terms of performance and management. In my specific case I needed to just install deps with a specific NPM version for local project I'm currently editing. This would require to keep it in sync with WSL - edit over SSH, or ditch realtime edits and sync over git, or else. Also WSL comes with a price - WSL1 is painfully slow for FS ops, and WSL2 doesn't play well with some other VM and requires RAM for its own VM.